# Android OGL 1.0: display object problems

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm a new in the OGL (1.0) world and i have a small problem. So i draw two panels and rotating them. The panels are angled 90 degrees to each other. When the panels are rotated, one of them always is shown on the front. But it should be behind the other in this moment!

[image]

Here is code `TexturedCube`

```
public class TexturedCube implements IFigure {
    private static final int VERTEX_SIZE = (3 + 2) * 4;
    private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    private int textureId;
    private float vertices[] = {
         1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1, 1, 
        -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0, 1, 
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0,

         1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1, 1,
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1, 0,
        -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0,

        1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1, 0, 
         1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0,
         1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0, 1,

         1.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1, 1,
         1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1, 0,
         1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0, 1,};
private float rotation = 0.1f;

public TexturedCube(int textureId) {
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
    vertexBuffer.flip();
    this.textureId = textureId;
}

@Override
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    rotation += 1.0f;
    gl.glRotatef(rotation, 1f, 0f, 0f);
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_SIZE, vertexBuffer);
    vertexBuffer.position(3);
    gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, VERTEX_SIZE, vertexBuffer);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 4 * 3);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
}

}
```

and `MainActivity`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    glView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
    glView.setRenderer(new MyOpenGLTextureRenderer());
    setContentView(glView);
}

private class MyOpenGLTextureRenderer implements Renderer {

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1f);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, .0f, -6.0f);
        cube.draw(gl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 45.0f, (float) width / (float) height, 0.1f, 100.0f);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        texture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.texture);
        int textureIds[] = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textureIds, 0);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureIds[0]);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, texture, 0);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
        GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        texture.recycle();
        cube = new TexturedCube(textureIds[0]);
    }

}
```

And if someone could advise me a good OGL tutorial with examples of android, it'll be perfect...

**EDIT:**
Here is solutions

you have to add `gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);` in `onSurfaceChanged()` in the `Activity`

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        ....
}
```

Comment: You should enable Z-buffering

Comment: You seem to be missing a depth buffer or just forgot to clear it. Try implementing that. With no depth buffer everything will always be drawn and if the object in front is drawn later then the one in the back it will produce the result you got.

Comment: Could you provide me an any example?

Comment: Yeah, i've found! Thanks!!! I'm going to edit post with solution!